# How to get inner object value in localStorage getItem in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to get the inner object value in localStorage.i.e object inside the object.

```
var filter = {
    filterWord: null,
    userId: null                
}
filter.filterWord = listCAO.sortName;
filter.userId = listCAO.currentUser;
listCAO.filterBreadcumText.push(filter);
localStorage.setItem('entityBreadCumText', listCAO.filterBreadcumText);
```

Comment: use [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) in your application.

Comment: web storage only holds strings. Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 4):

LocalStorage only holds String pairs: 'string1'='string2'

So when you do localStorage.getItem('string1') it returns 'string2'.

If you want to store a Javascript Object, you need to convert it into a string first. JSON works best for that.

```
var myObj = [{'name': 'Paul', 'age': 22}, {'name': 'Steve', 'age': 68}];
myStr = JSON.stringify(myObj);
localStorage.setItem('myData', myStr);
```

Same when you read the data from localStorage

```
var myStr = localStorage.getItem('myData');
var myObj = JSON.parse(myStr);
var myName = myObj[0].name;
```

Or in one step

```
var myName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'))[0].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be another solution.
You can use it this way.

```
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('your_settings_name'));
let lobj: YourObject = <YourObject>obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data is stored as *nested objects* instead of an array as c14l 's answer, the syntax changes a little bit.
Let's store *nested object* first:

```
var myNestedObject = {"token": "Bearer", "profile": {"name":"Mustafa","expires_at":1678013824}};
myNestedStr = JSON.stringify(myNestedObject);
localStorage.setItem('myNestedData', myNestedStr);
```

Now let's see how to get the "**name**" from the nested object:

```
var nestedStr = localStorage.getItem('myNestedData');
var nestedObj = JSON.parse(nestedStr);
var nestedProfile = nestedObj.profile;
var nestedName = nestedProfile.name;
```

Or we can get "**name**" with a single line also:

```
var nestedNameWithOneLine = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myNestedData')).profile.name;
```